# Assigning Random numbers to different Objects

Tags: java

I have a function that generates numbers randomly using Poisson's Distribution and I have a Bus class and a Bus Stop class as well. Now I have generated 5 bus objects and 15 bus stop objects. My goal here is to assign random numbers to these five bus objects to indicate their bus stop positions.

```
private static int getPoissonRandom(double mean){
Random r = new Random();
double L = Math.exp(-mean);
int k = 0;
double p = 1.0;
do {
    p = p * r.nextDouble();
    k++;
} while (p > L);
return k - 1;
}
```

Bus Stop Class

```
public class busStop {
int bus_stop_id;
public busStop(){    
  this.bus_stop_id=bus_stop_id;
} 
public void create_busStop(int total,int position){
   for(int i=1; i<=total; i++){
        bus_stop_id=i;
        //System.out.println("Bus_Stop with ID:"+i+" Spawned");
        setBusPosition(i,position);
    }
}
public void setBusPosition(int bus_id, int stop_id){
    System.out.println("Bus : "+bus_id+ " at Stop :"+stop_id);
    }
 }
```

Bus class

```
public class Bus {
int capacity;
int bus_id=0;



public Bus(){
  this.capacity=50;    
  this.bus_id=bus_id;
} 

public void spawn_bus(int bus_total){
    for(int i=1; i<=bus_total; i++){
        bus_id=i;
        System.out.println("Bus with ID:"+i+" created");
    }
}
```

}

Main Function

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
  int bus_number=5;  
  int total_bus_stops=15; 
  Bus bus = new Bus();
 busStop stops = new busStop();
 getPoissonRandom(5);
 bus.spawn_bus(bus_number);
 stops.create_busStop(total_bus_stops,getPoissonRandom(5));

}
```

when I run the code, I keep getting one number assigned to all 5 bus objects, but I want different random numbers using  Poisson Distribution generator to be assigned to the 5 bus objects

Comment: Please indicate in your question what happens when you run your code and what you expect to happen

Comment: i've updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are facing this problem since you have called the random generation method once only. 
To achieve the desired output you need to call getPoissonRandom(double mean) inside create_busStopMethod 
something like that :

```
    public void create_busStop(int total,int position){
   for(int i=1; i<=total; i++){
        bus_stop_id=i;
        //System.out.println("Bus_Stop with ID:"+i+" Spawned");
        setBusPosition(i,MainClass.getPoissonRandom(position));
    }
}
```

and then call the method as

```
stops.create_busStop(total_bus_stops,5);
```

or you can modify creat_busStop to accept id and position rather than total_bus_stops as follows:

```
public void create_busStop(int id,int position){
    bus_stop_id=id;
    setBusPosition(id,position);
}
```

}

and then call the method within for loop as

```
for(int i=0;i<total_bus_stops;i++){
stops.create_busStop(i,getPoissonRandom(5));
}
```